# how to use old style sql in mvc4

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC4 and I got the idea of Entity Framework. But I wonder how you do the old style sql statements in MVC 4.

lets say I have this action with EF code

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var model = from r in restaruants
                select r;
    return View(model);
}
```

Is it possible to do a old style sql instead of EF in the index function?

what I mean with old style sql is like "select * from restaurant"

```
public ActionResult Index(){
   /* Can I have something like this? */
   var model = Return_Model_Somehow("select * from restaurants");

   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Old style SQL is means ADO.NET?

Comment: like "select * from restaurant"

Comment: so you mean linq to sql?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can execute raw sql with `SqlQuery` method:

```
var model = context.Database.SqlQuery<Restauraunt>("SELECT * FROM Restaruants")
                   .ToList();
return View(model);
```

Here is MSDN article: [Raw SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx).

Comment: thank you very much. I will mark it as soon as system will let me

Comment: @ayilmaz welcome) but why really you need this, if you have whole power of Entity Framework?

Comment: I think my question was very obvious and it was a very common question to new learners

Comment: It is possible, and I had a case where I was using EF and all is fine, until I had to use a query which call oracle packages/functions, so I found copying the query as it is, the definite solution.

Answer (score 4):

MVC (All versions) do not suppose/force any data access method, if you mean 'Linq' then:

```
string q = "SELECT *FROM Table1";
IEnumerable<Entities.Table1> res = context.ExecuteQuery<Entities.Table1>(q);
```

Now you have the result as an enumerable collection, use it as you want.

Hope that helps.